# how launch webpack dev server for Electron.js App

Tags: webpack, electron

I develop project in custom way (for more handy) and I need to create dev env.
I use Webpack5 for creating dev server with HMR mode.

When I launch my script (which config and run webpack dev server) I have nothing error throw BUT also nothing append.

Can anyone help me to understand and create Webpack dev server for Electron app ?

**My webpack.config.js**

```
import path                         from 'path'
import webpack                      from 'webpack'
import {VueLoaderPlugin}              from 'vue-loader'
import HTMLWebpackPlugin            from 'html-webpack-plugin'
import url                          from "url"
import nodeExternals                from 'webpack-node-externals'

const __filename        = url.fileURLToPath(import.meta.url)
const __dirname         = path.dirname(__filename)
const buildDir          = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'build')
const mainEntryFile     = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'src', 'main', 'main.js')
const indexHTMLFile     = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'src', 'renderer', 'index.html')
const rendererEntryFile = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'src', 'renderer', 'renderer.js')
const componentDir      = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'src', 'renderer/components')
const nodeModulesDir    = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'node_modules')
const srcDir            = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'src')

console.log('======= ComponentsDir : ' + componentDir)
console.log('======= BuildDir : ' + buildDir)
console.log('======= srcdDir : ' + srcDir)
console.log('======= mainEntryFile : ' + mainEntryFile)

let webpackConfig =
{
    entry: {
        main: mainEntryFile,
        app: rendererEntryFile
    },

    output: {
        path: buildDir,
        filename: 'main-[name].js'
    },

    mode: "development",
    devtool: 'eval',
    target: 'electron-renderer',
    // externals: [nodeExternals()],
    // stats: 'errors-only',

    node: {
        __dirname: false,
        __filename: false
    },

    resolve: {
        alias: {
            // this isn't technically needed, since the default `vue` entry for bundlers
            // is a simple `export * from '@vue/runtime-dom`. However having this
            // extra re-export somehow causes webpack to always invalidate the module
            // on the first HMR update and causes the page to reload.
            vue: "@vue/runtime-dom",
            // env: path.resolve(__dirname, `./env_${envName(env)}.json`)
            "@": srcDir,
            '@vueComponents': 'src/renderer/components'
        },
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.json'],
    },

    // resolveLoader: {
    //     modules: [
    //         nodeModulesDir
    //     ]
    // },

    module: {
        rules: [
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
                presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
            }
        },
        {
            test: /\.ts?$/,
            use: 'ts-loader',
            exclude: /node_modules/,
        },
        {
            test: /.vue$/,
            loader: 'vue-loader',
            options: {
                esModule: true
            }
        },
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: [
                'vue-style-loader',
                'css-loader'
            ]
        }]
    },

    plugins: [
            new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
            new VueLoaderPlugin(),
            new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
                showErrors: true,
                cache: true,
                template: indexHTMLFile
            })
        ]
}

export default webpackConfig
```

**my dev-server-webpack.js (for launching webpack) :**

```
import webpack                        from 'webpack'
import WebpackDevServer               from 'webpack-dev-server'
import webpackConfig                  from '../config/webpack.config.js'
import path                           from 'path'
import url                            from 'url'

console.log('---------------------------------------------')
console.log('Starting the webpack dev web server script...')
console.log('---------------------------------------------')

const __filename = url.fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
console.log('Filename : ' + __filename)
console.log('Directory name : ' + path.dirname(__filename))

const server = new WebpackDevServer(webpack(webpackConfig), {})

server.start()
```

**And my output script log into console is :**

```
λ npm run webpack:dev                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 

> electron-vue-template@0.1.0 webpack:dev
> set NODE_ENV=development && node scripts/dev-server-webpack.js
runtime modules 54.1 KiB 24 modules
orphan modules 228 bytes [orphan] 8 modules
cacheable modules 736 KiB
  modules by path ./node_modules/ 724 KiB 35 modules
  modules by path ./src/ 11.9 KiB
    modules by path ./src/renderer/ 8.72 KiB
      modules by path ./src/renderer/components/*.vue 6.4 KiB 8 modules
      modules by path ./src/renderer/*.vue 2.11 KiB 5 modules
      ./src/renderer/renderer.js 212 bytes [built] [code generated]
    ./src/main/main.js 1.9 KiB [built] [code generated]
    ./src/service/router.ts 1.24 KiB [built] [code generated]
external "events" 42 bytes [built] [code generated]
external "electron" 42 bytes [built] [code generated]
webpack 5.66.0 compiled successfully in 4433 ms
```

Compilation webpack successful but nothing chromium launched...

What is the mechanism that authorize to launch a Chromium navigator (Electron) and the main process electron ?

I don't want to use electron-webpack because it normalize (thus force structure and others think that not corresponding for all project) config, structure, options or files.

Comment: you're not launching electron anywhere, you're just starting the dev server

Comment: Do you think about "spawn" command into webpack ?

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert on Electron but, after constant hours trying to sift through other resources, documentation, and trial and error, I have found what I believe to be a decent setup from scratch. I'm also in the work of making a secure, non-opinionated boilerplate for starting a new Electron app with comments and documentation explaining why certain things are configured the way they are. If you want to check it out, it's what I'm referencing here. I'm also glad to receive any feedback on it from anyone. [Secure Electron Boilerplate](https://github.com/lgoodcode/secure-electron-boilerplate)

When starting Electron, it consists of three parts: the main process, the preload script, and the renderer.

You'll bundle them separately, which Webpack includes targets for as well [here](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/target/).

What I did is use separate npm scripts for each one as well as create a start script to execute by node to do extra stuff.

Here is what that script looks like:

`scripts/start.ts`

```js
import { config as dotenv } from 'dotenv'
import webpack from 'webpack'
import WebpackDevServer from 'webpack-dev-server'
import chalk from 'chalk'
import runScript from './runScript'
import rendererConfig from '../config/webpack.config.renderer'

dotenv({ path: '.env.local' })

const compiler = webpack(rendererConfig)
const devServerOptions: WebpackDevServer.Configuration = {
    host: 'localhost',
    hot: true,
    compress: true,
    port: process.env.PORT || 8000,
    headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' },
    static: {
        publicPath: '/',
    },
    historyApiFallback: {
        verbose: true,
    },
}
const server = new WebpackDevServer(devServerOptions, compiler)

const startServer = async () => {
    console.log(chalk.cyan('Starting preload file processing...'))
    runScript('preload', 'npm', ['run', 'start:preload'])

    console.log(chalk.cyan('Starting main process...'))
    runScript('main', 'npm', ['run', 'start:main'])

    console.log(chalk.cyan('Starting renderer server...'))
    await server.start()
}

startServer()
```

This essentially does the following:

- Spawn a process to run the webpack for the preload file
- Spawn a process to run the webpack for the main process
- Start the dev server using the renderer file.

Here is what those npm scripts are doing:

```js
{
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development ts-node scripts/start.ts",
    "start:main": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development electronmon -r ts-node/register ./src/main/main.ts",
    "start:preload": "webpack --config config/webpack.config.preload.ts",
}
```

The single `npm start` call runs the other two processes before actually starting the server because they are required for the app to function. Now, you only need the preload file if you actually need to use it when making calls to NodeJS modules from the frontend.

Here is what's going on with this:

- The preload file is bundled into JavaScript so that the Chromium browser in Electron and load it.
- Electron is started on the main entry file with electromon.

Now, within the `src/main/main.ts` file, or wherever your entry file is for Electron with the main window. On the `preload` property, you need to specify where webpack outputs the bundled file. I specified a ternary operator based on whether the app is packaged or not. If not packaged, the file location is adjacent to the original with a `.dev` extension because it'll only be used for development.

`src/main/window.ts`

```js
import { app } from 'electron'
import { join } from 'path'

...

let mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    ...,
    webPreferences: {
        preload: app.isPackaged
            ? join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
            : join(srcPreloadPath, 'preload.dev.js'),
    }
})

...
```

If you want to see what the webpack configurations are, check out the repo I linked at the top. I hope this helps you and anyone else who is struggling to try to learn Electron. I'm also in the progress of learning so point out any errors I make please!

Comment: Is this better than Electron Forge? Or how is it different

Comment: @Simp4Code I haven't looked too much into Electron-Forge but, they seem like to Electron as CRA is to React. They have a lot going on in the background and I like to see all the code that is being used when learning something new.